# fluentd bigquery plugin with Navigator.sendBeacon

Tags: google-bigquery, fluentd

I have the fluentd plugin for Bigquery setup and it's been working really great when I use HTTP POST/GET to send JSON payload, but I wanted to try and switch to using [Navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)
The problem is that this API doesn't let me configure the type of payload and these are the ones supported:

> A ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, DOMString, FormData, or
> URLSearchParams object containing the data to send.

So when using it as is it the plugin doesn't accept the request.
Is there any way to either explicitly state the payload is JSON or configure/alter the plugin to support the types mentioned above ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can use `Blob` type to send text which can be in JSON format. You should use and test this first. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem I think that's the right approach!
I am now facing some CROS issues but it seems that the configuring the request as JSON is solved when using `Blob`